U.S Citizen married to Danish Citizen living in Sweden with active resident card application - Can we travel to Denmark together?
I am married to a Danish citizen who moved to Sweden in August 2023. We applied for the resident card in December 2023. Our application is still pending and I have family coming out in November. Am I allowed to travel with my wife to Denmark to pick up my family? I have a valid US passport, Swedish ID Card (not resident card), Swedish Personal Number and our marriage certificate available on my phone.

Is your question about entry to Denmark or reentry to Sweden? Your question seems to be about the former, but your comment on Mark Johnson's answer seems to be about the latter?

@StrangerToKindness indeed.  It's not uncommon for a country to consider s pending immigration application to be abandoned if the applicant leaves the country.  In this case it wouldn't prevent reentry, because of EU free movement law, but it might require a new resident card application.

As a Swedish citizen with a non Swedish spouse, when we went through the residence permit application, the rules were that the person applying was not allowed to enter Sweden until the application had been completed and the residence card issued. This was about 10 years ago so the rules might have changed though.

It’s about traveling from Sweden to Denmark for a day to pick up my family traveling to see me via CPH. Basically crossing the bridge via Malmö, picking them up at CPH and then traveling back to Sweden.

@DarkMatter Sweden can't impose that rule on people who benefit from the EU free movement directive because it is inconsistent with the directive's requirements.  This would include Swedish citizens returning to Sweden with their family members from another free-movement country, but the family members of Swedish citizens otherwise do not fall under the directive.

@phoog That does sound logical. In our case, my spouse was from out side EU. I was mostly thinking about Ashley who, if the rules are the same today, should not even be in Sweden while the residence permit application is being processed. So that could hypothetically be a problem when returning, though it's unlikely since there should be no passport control between DK and SE. Edit: I might have misunderstood things though.

@DarkMatter what I mean is that Sweden can't require non-EU family members of EU citizens to remain outside Sweden during the application.  In other words, the phrase "people who benefit from the EU free movement directive" in my previous comment refers to non-EU family members of EU citizens.  So the spouse of a Swedish citizen can be required to remain outside Sweden, but the spouse of a Danish citizen (or of a citizen of any other EU/EEA country or Switzerland) cannot.

@phoog I'm not familiar with EU law, or law in general beyond what's expected of a regular citizen, but the Swedish Migration Agency (Migrationsverket) is pretty clear on this point: "The decision must already have been taken before you travel to Sweden. " and "A residence permit cannot normally be granted if you are in Sweden."
It does mention exceptions though, at least in the Swedish version.
Source: https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Moving-to-someone-in-Sweden/Spouse-registered-partner-or-cohabiting-partner/Instructions-for-online-application.html

"decision" refers to the decision by the Migration Agency on your application.

@DarkMatter that page does not apply to family members of EU citizens who enjoy the right of free movement.  Their page is https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/EU-EEA-citizens/Work-study-or-live-in-Sweden-for-EU-EEA-citizens/Residence-cards-for-family-who-are-non-EU-EEA-citizens.html -- the page you linked to should be clearer about that; if it had been, Ashley probably would never have been in this situation.


Am I allowed to travel with my wife to Denmark to pick up my family?

Yes, as a US citizen you can (alone) travel from Sweden to Denmark (or any other Schengen county) based on the the 90/180 rule. When traveling with your EU-citizen spouse that rule does not apply (i.e. you can stay with your EU-citizen spouse up to 3 months in a single Schengen country.) Without the resident card you must supply other proof that you are the spouse of an EU-citizen.

our marriage certificate available on my phone

In the unlikely situation that anybody would be interested, that should be sufficient.
For a short visit your passport and Swedish ID card should be enough.

Hi Mark, Based on the information you provided, i should be allowed to travel into Denmark for a day as long as my wife is with me and I prove my relation to her with the marriage certificate? I just wanted to clarify. I’ve received multiple responses across different platforms that i’m not allowed to leave Sweden until my resident card application is processed.

Yes, you can (both alone or with your wife). 'that i’m not allowed to leave Sweden until my resident card application is processed': that is only true if your citizenship requires a Schengen Visa to enter the Schengen Area. That is not the case for US citizens.

@Ashley if you're concerned about leaving Sweden, you should consider asking the relevant authorities in Sweden and Denmark.  This answer is certainly correct about European Union free movement law, but authorities occasionally adopt interpretations of the law that are contrary to its spirit or even its explicit provisions.  Another important consideration is your pending application.
Some countries will consider it abandoned if you leave while it is pending.  If this is the reason for the advice you've seen about not leaving Sweden then you may want to ask a new question about that.
